# Getting Undefined index when making a session

Tags: javascript, php

Hi I'm trying to make a session in my main page but its just giving me an error of undefined index in uniqueID line 5.

The connection between my webqr.js and server.php have no errors but when I tried to connect it to my wow.php it gives me an error of undefined index.

webqr.js Code

```
function read(a){

   var html=htmlEntities(a);

   var audio = new Audio('lib/beep.ogg');
   audio.play();

   var uniqueID = document.getElementById("mapo").innerHTML= html;      

    window.location.href = "http://localhost/QR_JEFF/server.php?uniqueID=" + uniqueID; }
```

server.php Code

```
    session_start();
    $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','suffrage');
        $uniqueID =  $_GET['uniqueID'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM applicant_table WHERE unique_id='$uniqueID'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);


        if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {


      $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
      if($logged_in_user['validation_status'] == 'Verified' && $logged_in_user['voting_status'] == 'No'){

      $_SESSION['unique_id'] = $uniqueID;
      $_SESSION['validation_status'] = $logged_in_user;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";

      header('location: wow.php');
    }

  }
```

wow.php Code

```
<?php include('server.php');?>


  <?php  if (isset($_SESSION['unique_id'])) : ?>
  Welcome User:
  <input type="text" value="<?php  echo $_SESSION['unique_id']; ?>" disabled>
  <?php endif ?>
```

[Now I'm receiving this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfrL5.png)

Comment: where are you starting your session? 
session_start(); use this before your assigning value to session.
session_start();
$_SESSION['unique_id'] = $uniqueID;
      $_SESSION['validation_status'] = $logged_in_user;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";

Comment: I have session_start(); I forgot to copy and paste it here. I'll update my code. But still no luck. :(

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: Also, **never** get your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes,
so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities
this just leaves your database an open book for hackers.
Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually _needs_ in order to work properly.
Don't even do this is a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

Comment: `uniqueID` isn't this should be an integer? did you check the result of uniqueID inside your js?
is it correct?

Comment: Thank you for your advice **ADyson** I will try to learn more on how to secure my database. Im just a beginner in php. :)

Comment: I tried printing my uniqueID in both js and server.php and it works. I dont know why when I create a session in wow.php it becomes undefined.

Comment: try dumping your `$_SESSION` array `var_dump($_SESSION);` to check it inside `wow.php`

Comment: I tried to rework my code and now Im getting this error. See above I provide a picture of the error.

Comment: This is the new error                                                                                    Notice: Undefined index: uniqueID in C:\xampp\htdocs\QR_JEFF\server.php on line 7
Welcome User:  
15b4f14833c116

Answer (score 0):

okay so this solve my own question.

```
            session_start();
        if(isset($_GET['uniqueID'])){
        $uniqueID = " ";
        $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','suffrage');
        $uniqueID =  $_GET['uniqueID'];
        $query = "SELECT * FROM applicant_table WHERE unique_id='$uniqueID'";
        $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);


      if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {
      $logged_in_user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);
      if($logged_in_user['validation_status'] == 'Verified' && $logged_in_user['voting_status'] == 'No'){

      $_SESSION['unique_id'] = $uniqueID;
      $_SESSION['validation_status'] = $logged_in_user;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";


      header('location: wow.php');               
    }

  }

}
```

I put my code in another if statement.